# AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'pop' in plt.title func of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want put a caculated value in title, and it can work

```
plt.title(sum_auc)
```

However,if I add "AUC:", it didn't work

```
plt.title("AUC:",sum_auc)
```

and show no attribute 'pop'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast sum_auc as str

```
plt.title(f"AUC:{sum_auc}")
```

Or

```
plt.title("AUC:"+str(sum_auc))
```

Comment: it can work plt.title(sum_auc), even though didn't add str func. I mean why it didn't work when add "AUC:"

Comment: So try plt.title(f"AUC:{sum_auc}")

Comment: Or plt.title("AUC:"+str(sum_auc))